# Using Sed to replace character after pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I'm working on a file with a "special" pattern and I need to harmonize the file to import it later.

Sample:

```
mail@adress.dot;city;phone
mail@adress.dot:city;phone
mail@adress.dot:city;phone
mail@adress.dot;city;phone
```

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/\:/;/g' myfiles
```

But this replaces all `:` and I need to replace only the `:` after the mail address.
And mail addresses are not all the same all form different provider.

Sample to clear what is the problem with the `;` or `:`

```
john@doe.dot;city;000:000:000
john@do.us:city;000;000;000
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the first occurrence only? Remove `g`, `sed -i 's/:/;/' files`

Comment: Yeah, remove `g`lobal. And if it's about harmony, I would also suggest `sed -i 's/d/dd/' files`.

Comment: I only want to replace if it is after the email address

because of the phone number

if I have one; the telephone number is separated by:

and

if I have one: the phone number is separated by;

This is why I am looking to replace only after the email address and then work on the phone number

Comment: @ozer, this is totally unclear to me. Please add/edit the sample input as well as the desired output in a way that both are **representative of your usecase**. If on some lines there's a phone number and on others there's not a phone number, please show us an example of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get fields and delimiters into arrays. Second, format the output as required.

```
awk '
{
    split($0, field, /[;:]/)
    split($0, delim, /[^;:]+/)
    delim[2] = ":"
    for (i = 1; i in field; i++)
        printf "%s", field[i] delim[i + 1]
    printf "\n"
}
' input.file
```

Comment: How i can make it works in all directories and subdirectories